# Android - Download a zip file from Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase

I've implemented a button which should allow me to download a zip file from Firebase Storage.

This is my code

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

.buttonCtaClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //download stuff
                        try {
                            File imageFile = File.createTempFile("Chords_Images", "zip");

                            storageRef.getFile(imageFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "file created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    //TODO: download audio
                                    startApp();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "An error accoured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                    }
                })
```

The problem is that it always fails and calls the `FailureListener` how can this happen?

this is the stacktrace of the Exception:

> error getting token java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: firebase-auth is not linked, please fall back to unauthenticated mode.
>   07-22 11:33:57.991 4272-4417/com.dancam.chords E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
>                                                                      User does not have permission to access this object

This is my firebase storage rules

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/chords-d1534.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true; //if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try printing `Exception e`'s text, and show us your `storageRef`.

Comment: Can you post also your firebase storage rules?

Comment: @sudo done, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are downloading the file in a wrong way. Your reference to a file should be:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
final StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child("path/to/file.zip");
```

And use it:

```
imageRef.getFile(imageFile).addOnSuccess...
```

---

If it did not fix the problem, let's take a look at the error message.

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseApiNotAvailableException: **firebase-auth is not linked**, please fall back to unauthenticated mode. 07-22 11:33:57.991 4272-4417/com.dancam.chords

Try linking the `firebase-auth` library (add this into your app-level `build.gradle`):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
```

Comment: the path is the root dir of my Firebase Storage, what path do I need to write in the code?

Comment: Then write `filename.zip`.

Comment: @Daniele If the solution worked for you, please make sure to accept the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149878/discussion-between-daniele-and-sudo).